# How to publish single document of a collection for a group of fields with common values in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to create a publication which should return documents which have a different value for a set of fields. For example, if have a collection called  `'User'` with below transactions:

```
{
  userId: 1,
  date: '12-1-15',
  amount: 450
}
{
  userId: 1,
  date: '12-1-15',
  amount: 250
}
{
  userId: 2,
  date: '12-1-15',
  amount: 100
}
{
  userId: 2,
  date: '11-1-15',
  amount: 200
}
```

Then i need to create a query which will publish only the below documents, i.e, single document for each day and if a day has multiple documents then i want to publish only the document with highest amount.

```
 [{
  userId: 1,
  date: '12-1-15',
  amount: 450
},
{
  userId: 2,
  date: '12-1-15',
  amount: 100
}
{
  userId: 2,
  date: '11-1-15',
  amount: 200
}]
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Does it matter if it isn't reactive? How many documents are there? This is a type of publisher that is really difficult to implement in meteor.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this data? The best solution might be to subscribe in multiple templates instead of trying to publish it all in one query

Comment: @DavidWeldon, Yes it should be reactive. Even if its difficult any pointers are highly welcomed. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @merlinpatt, This is just an example of my scenario. In my application it is mandatory that it should come from same publication. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why is it mandatory that it should all come from the same publication?